# Optimizing Python polynomial evaluation

Tags: python, optimization, polynomial-math

I have a function which evaluates terms of a polynomial in several variables. The inputs are lists of powers of each variable. For example, for two variables and 2nd order it looks like this,

```
def f(x,y):
    return [1, x[1], y[1], x[1]*y[1], x[2], y[2]]

x = [2**0, 2**1, 2**2]
y = [3**0, 3**1, 3**2]

>>> f(x,y)
[1,2,3,6,4,9]
```

In reality the function is higher order and has many variables so on average there are a few thousand terms (in fact, I create the function at run time with an eval statement, but that's not important). The function is on an inner most loop and is currently a speed bottleneck. The profiler tells me I spend most of the time in __times__.

Short of creating a C extension module, can anyone see any room for optimization?

**Edit:** The example above is trying to evaulate `1 + x + y + xy + x^2 + y^2` with `x = 2`and `y = 3`, except without adding them, just putting each term in a list.

Adding them is fine (with some coefficients A, B, ...) i.e. all I'm trying to do is compute:

`A + B*x + C*y + D*x*y + E*x^2 + F*y^2`.

Comment: How often is the function called with similar or the same arguments?

Comment: I'm really not sure about what your script does, but have you tried looking into scipy/numpy?

Comment: @NolenRoyalty good question, unfortunately the answer is that each variable is different every time.

Comment: Can the functions be described using recursion in such a way that you could cache previous values to calculate future ones?

Comment: @NolenRoyalty Hmm... I don't think caching anything would help, each time a new x,y, etc... is picked randomly and the polynomial gets evaluated.

Comment: @RikPoggi The only relevant package I've found is numpy.polynomial but that has support only for polynomials in one variable.

Comment: Is x (or y) an array for the *same* number? It seems so in your example, where x is for 2, and y is for 3?

Comment: @KayZhu yes, each array contains precomputed powers of some number (this was the first bit of optimization which I did)

Comment: I know undestand, everything is hardcoded... You're trying to evaluate `1 + x + y + xy + x^2 + y^2` with `x = 2` and `y = 3`, is that right?

Comment: @marius so I assume the `__times__` that is taking most of the time just refers to the `x[1]*y[1]` part in `f(x,y)`, not the `*` in `x=[2**0, 2**1, 2**2]`?

Comment: @RikPoggi exactly (except without adding them, just putting each term in a list) sorry I didn't make that more clear

Comment: @KayZhu correct, in my simple example only one single term even contained a multiplication, but in more variables and higher order, there's tons of multiplications

Comment: Than it's not a polynomial evaluation... Is it a requirement not adding them? BTW in `numpy.polynomial`, there's [`polyval2d(x,y,c)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval2d.html), couldn't that help?

Comment: why are you creating the x,y lists? how mant times? whats the lenght of x, y?

Comment: Adding them is fine (with some coefficients A, B, ...) i.e. all I'm trying to do is compute A + B*x + C*y + D*x*y + E*x^2 + F*y^2. I didn't notice the polyval2d and polyval3d in that package, which aren't directly useful because I need higher order, but I AM going to go look at their code and see what they're doing, thanks!

Comment: @ChessMaster The x,y are just there for optimization, to avoid computing x**n multiple times. Typically I go to O(10)th order, so they're length 10.

Comment: @marius: Since it seemed appropriate, I summurized my/our comments into an answer, I've also edited your question to add there more information, that you provided here by comments.

Comment: is this your f? `def f(x,y,k): return [ (x**n)*(y**m) for m,n in product(range(k),repeat=2)] + [x**k,y**k]` x=2,y=3,k=2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure from which version, but numpy should have a [`polyval2d(x,y,c)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval2d.html) function into the [`polynomial`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.polynomials.polynomial.html) module, that will perfectly apply to your example.

You seemed interested in expanding your example to a much higher dimension.

In the same module there's a [`polyval3d(x,y,z,c)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval3d.html), if that's not enought I'd suggest (as I guess you're already doing) to look at the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/polynomial/polynomial.py#L789). It shouldn't be too hard to implement what best suits your needs, and you can always ask here on SO :)

Comment: Aha, that DID help. What I was looking for is something called [Horner's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner's_method). The idea is that instead of evaluating 1 + x + y + x^2 + y^2 + x y,  you evaluate 1 + y (1 + y) + x (1 + x + y) which involves fewer operations.

Answer (score 0):

> The function is on an inner most loop and is currently a speed
>   bottleneck.

You could try to get rid of the loop altogether, by using NumPy and replacing your variables with arrays of higher dimension.

Comment: A good idea but I don't know the next values of x,y, etc... until after I evaluate the function, so I can't vectorize it.